# WPF : Clear TextBox text after enter key press

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have textbox in my WPF application, i have binded one commandproperty with it , after inserting value once i press enter key , it's value gets added in ObservableCollection object. i have used TextBox input binding below is the code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBox1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="15,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" >
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=InsertCommand1}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txtBox1}" Key="Enter" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Here is the viewmodel's property

```
private ICommand _insertCommand1;
    public ICommand InsertCommand1
    {
        get
        {
            if (_insertCommand1 == null)
                _insertCommand1 = new RelayCommand(param => AddItem1((String)param));
            return _insertCommand1;
        }
    }

    private void AddItem1(string res)
    {
        this.CollectionList.Add(Int32.Parse(res));
    }
```

Here i want textbox to be cleared once i add data in collection. i even tried with KeyDown event handler in code behind like below but it didn't get clear.

```
    private void txtBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            txtBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're going about it oddly...

First, bind a property of the ViewModel to the TextBox

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TheTextBoxValue}" />
```

and (INotifyPropertyChanged implementation details omitted)

```
public string TheTextBoxValue 
{ 
    get { return _ttbv; }
    set { _ttbv = vaule; NotifyOnPropertyChangedImplementationLol(); }
}
```

Now, you can use TheTextBoxValue and clear it out from your VM

```
private void AddItem1(string res)
{
    // Who needs validation? LIVE ON THE EDGE!
    this.CollectionList.Add(Int32.Parse(TheTextBoxValue));
    // or, if you use validation, after you successfully parse the value...
    TheTextBoxValue = null;
}
```

Comment: @PraveenDeewan this is an answer, not a comment. You can also click the checkmark by the vote count to tell others that this is a correct answer and that it helped you to solve your problem.  That's normally how things are done here :)